# CountIF With Manual Text Indents

Tags: excel, countif

I'm trying to count the specific times a word occurs, but I'm also using a manual indent in my cell. It is for groups of four in which each person answers a Yes/No question. Therefore, there's a number of possibilities that could occur. For example:
[image: Example Image]

I would rather not make them their own cell, because they need to be under one group. And I am unable to use a merge because I need to keep it formatted as a table.

Is it possible to make a formula that counts the amount of "Yes" answers and the amount of "No" answers? Thank you.

Comment: For each cell or altogether?

Comment: Altogether. So for the attached picture, I would want it to count 7 "Yes" responses and 5 "No" responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN($B$1:$B$3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B$1:$B$3,C5,REPT("|",LEN(C5)-1))))*1)
```

[image]

Comment: That did it! I tweaked it to be self contained by adding "Yes" and "No" instead of C5 and C6, but it works for everything I need. Thank you, that's just solved a huge headache.